# django project with private app

Tags: django

Currently I have a django project called Foobar. It consists of several apps that work together. Most of them are basic utilities for this one app(called `star`) that is the *secret sauce*.

What I would like to do is is invite people to contribute to the project (to all it's utility apps) but not be able to see `star`. I wish `star` be closed sourced and developed only by the core team.

How can I handle this? Should I move `star` to another repository on Github? Moreover, **how do I deploy this project**?

Needless to say `star` needs all the utility apps to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding the `star/` app (directory) into the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: but the code should be on github as well, so that the core team can collaborate on it. Also, when deploying, need it on github. At the same time, it should be closed source

Comment: Then you should have 2 repos. One for the collaboration team (with the `star` app) and one for the public (without the `star` app). Then, you should handle the [github webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) approprietly to push/pull changes to the correct origin.

Comment: What about deployment? How can it be deployed as one django project?

Comment: Each time you are ready to deploy your project, you should merge any potential "public" pull requests to the origin of the "collaboration repo" (which will contain the `star` app) and then deploy (do not forget to include the `star`). Maybe [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) maybe of help!

Comment: The open source utility apps will have the bulk of the code, and I have closed source `star`. When I deploy, you suggest I pull `star` in open source repo and deploy. Locally too, to test `star`, the core team can pull it into public repo and test?

Comment: Something like that, yes. If I was in your place, I would do it like that by using fabric to make my life easier!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137737/discussion-between-darshan-chaudhary-and-nik-m).